# If $y^3 + 3a^2x + x^3 = 0,$ then prove that $y'' + \frac{2a^2x^2}{y^5} = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am comfortable with second derivatives but I am just unable to set all the variables up in such a format that I get the latter (the part which needs to be proven). A hint would be a lot of help.

Comment: Please check that I did not change the intent of the question!

Comment: You didn't, sir

Comment: Have you computed the second derivative?

Comment: I did but actually the thing is, I am new to these problems and these require some getting used to (I think). I pondered on it with pen and paper and ended up with nothing, and later figured that it'd be a better idea to get help from more experienced people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use "implicit differentiation" to start, here:

$$ y^3 + 3a^2x + x^3 = 0 $$
$$ 3y^2y' + 3a^2 + 3x^2 = 0 \implies y^2y' + a^2 + x^2 = 0 $$
$$ 6yy'^2 + 3y^2y'' + 6x = 0 \implies 2yy'^2 + y^2y'' + 2x = 0 $$

Then a bit of algebra gives:

$$ y'' + \frac{2yy'^2 + 2x}{y^2} = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 0 $$
$$ y'' + \frac{2y\left(\frac{-a^2 - x^2}{y^2}\right)^2 + 2x}{y^2} = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 0 $$
$$ y'' + \frac{2\left(-a^2 - x^2\right)^2 + 2\left(-3ax^2 - x^3\right)x}{y^5} = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 0 $$

If you then simplify further, you should find you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate twice,

$$y^2y'+a^2+x^2=0$$

and

$$2yy'^2+y^2y''+2x=0.$$

Then multiplying by $y^3$ and substituting,

$$2y^4y'^2+y^5y''+2xy^3=2(a^2+x^2)^2+y^5y''-2x(3a^2x+x^3)=0.$$

This simplifies to

$$y^5y''+2a^2(a^2-x^2)=0,$$ and the claim seems wrong.

Comment: Which claim? The latter claim of what we have to prove? I am not sure as it's one of the problems of an assignment we were given. It could be the case though I'll only be able to tell when I try the solutions given here myself.

Comment: As confirmed by @farruhota, the given answer in the OP is wrong. You should consider accepting an answer that shows it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also differentiate explicitely:
$$y=(-3a^2x-x^3)^{1/3}.$$
$$y'=\frac13 (-3a^2x-x^3)^{-2/3}\cdot (-3a^2-3x^2).$$
$$y''=-\frac{2}{3^2}(-3a^2x-x^3)^{-5/3}\cdot (-3a^2-3x^2)^2+\frac13 (-3a^2x-x^3)^{-2/3}\cdot (-6x)=$$
$$-\frac{2(a^2+x^2)^2}{y^5}-\frac{2x}{y^2}=\frac{-2(a^2+x^2)^2-2x(-3a^2x-x^3)}{y^5}=\frac{2a^2x^2-2a^4}{y^5}$$

Answer (score 0):

by differentiating with respect to $x$ we get
$$3y^2\cdot y'+3a^2+3x^2=0$$ (I) from here we get
$$y'=-\frac{a^2+x^2}{y^2}$$ and $$y\ne 0$$
differentiating again we have
$$2y\cdot (y')^2+y^2y''+2x=0$$ (II)
now you can plug in the equation for $y'$ in (II) note that if we differentiate $$y^3$$ we get $$3y^2\cdot y'$$

Comment: you must use the Chaine rule $$(y^3)^'=3y^2y'$$

Comment: yes that is what i meant, thank you

Comment: you don't Need to say sorry it was an error or typo

Comment: Perhaps I'll ask this in another thread, doesn't simply differentiating $y'$ give the same answer?

Comment: but you have $$y^2$$ in the denominator and you will get $$y'$$ again